# How to store data in memory in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Our app has to log users' actions pretty frequently (10~15s), and it can be pretty heavy IO. Therefore we do not want to store the data into the database every time when user updates something, and we want to store everything in memory (eg an array), and then store them into the database when the memory reaches certain size.The log of different users should go to the same memory, for our purpose.

We have done some cache on the client side already, but we want to optimize it further on the server.

Is there any good way in ROR to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Define where exactly "in memory" is? On a rails app - the database *is* your memory.

Comment: Take a look into redis, an incredibly quick key-value memory store.

Comment: @TarynEast Hi, here I mean RAM

Comment: @silverwen on which computer? Server-side? if so - please refer to what I said above. Note: you can basically assume that after every request in Rails (or any server-side stateless app), anything in RAM is deleted so the RAM can be reused by the next request (by another person). If you mean client-side computer - that's a different story and you must use client-side code (which is not rails eg javascript) to do any storing on the local client's machine.

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast. It is on the server side. But frequent queries to database will bring a very heavy IO, and we are trying to minimize this cost. We know that RAM cannot be used between requests, so we are wondering if there are some ways to keep the RAM between requests

Comment: Not directly. you can't keep anything between requests that is not stored in a datastore of some kind. A database is one kind... redis or memcached are  the other, faster options (they work alongside your db, so you have both). but you can't just directly store stuff in RAM and use it - it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common issue. If you are interested in caching data structures Redis is lightning fast memory-based data structure server which is commonly used to lighten the load on the disk-based database. Here is a recent, as of 2015, article on the subject. http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-model-caching-redis/

Rails also has native memory-based cache features if you don't want to use Redis or Memcached: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store

Comment: Great answer errata! Thanks a lot! One thing I am not very sure: if I use Rails cache, it needs to set an expiration time, and the example in the documentation seems to use that cache mainly for caching request response, so is rails cache suitable for my case here ?  (maybe I miss something in the documentation)

Comment: you can put anything into an object cache - eg an array of values - which you then pull out and add to, then put back in the cache. if it gets big enough, you can then flush/persist it to the db.